# Markdown 'tag:x' fails to render tags with non-ASCII characters as tags

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, internationalization

In Markdown posts or comments, `[tag:x]` is supposed to create a little tag icon + link. However, this fails for non-ASCII characters:

- `[tag:featured]` results in [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), which is correct
- `[tag:важное]` results in [tag:важное], which is incorrect

A screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of rendering]

Comment: Looks like it does work on localized sites (e.g. see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqOFm.png)) so can't see any problem. Only the localized sites needs it.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard I wanted to use it on meta, in a post comparing how when I search across all of Stack Exchange for [tag:featured] it does also show [tag:важное].  It does also work in chat.